# How v4l2loopback makes a previously ignored udev rule work?

Tags: udev, void-linux, v4l2loopback

I've found the "how", but am curious about "why".

I've got an `udev` rule for a Sony camera that didn't work:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0cae", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0774", SYMLINK+="sony%n"
```

Specifically, the camera was connected and appeared under `/dev/bus/usb/00<X>/00<Y>`, but the permissions and group were not applied from the `udev` rule. When I've changed permissions on the device file (it's ugly, but this is a sandbox system), I was actually able to capture an image with `gphoto2`. So I thought it narrows the question to why a `udev` rule was ignored.

Interestingly, after installing `v4l2loopback` package and loading the module with

```
modprobe v4l2loopback
```

everything worked like a charm. Permissions, group, a symlink to `/dev/sony<X>` was created. The `v4l2loopback` package has no dependencies, the `udev` rules do not seem to have changed.

This took place on Void Linux with dwm window manager.

Could someone explain why it worked?